# UIButton title text selecting a particular text and Copy it

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

How can I select a particular text from UIButton title text and copy it like UITextField?

Comment: you can use `currentTitle` property of `UIButton`

Comment: Hey, can you please add more detail to your question, please?

Comment: you cant do text selection on a button. Buttons are not meant for that. You can achieve it by creating a custom view

Comment: I agree with @KeshuRai.

Comment: or you can copy the entire button title on button click.

Comment: i agree with @KeshuRai buttons job is to perform action, not for selecting the content.

Answer (score 0):

```
let text = self.yourButton.titleLabel.text

UIPasteboard.general.string = text
```

Store your button title in the text variable where btn1 will be your button.

And UIPasteboard will copy that variable text.

Comment: The question is about how to copy a particular text from the button title, not complete title

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.btn setTitle:@"some string" forState:UIControlStateReserved];

NSString *strMessage = [self.btn titleForState:UIControlStateReserved];
UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[pb setString:strMessage];
```

Store your button title in the text variable where btn will be your button.

And UIPasteboard pb will copy that variable text.

Comment: This is not the answer. His question is `select a particular text from UIButton like we select text in text field`. Your solution is not satisfy the asked question.

Comment: Yes Mahendra. I want to select a particular text from UIButton title text and copy it.

Comment: In reserved state you can store any value and than you can retrieve anytime you want